# Error Downloading SMS logs in Twilio logs page

Tags: twilio

getting this error "Could not finish exporting all records." while trying to export all SMS sent from my account on a particular date using programming logs interface in twilio portal.

number of records is roughly ~15,000 and error shows up at line 10,001.

Are there any other recommend ways to download the logs ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried doing it in batches?

Comment: What code are you using to export the the SMS logs?

Comment: twilio portal's logs page with 'export to csv' button.